# Upgrade to GSL 2.4+ in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, libraries

I have GSL libraries version 2.1 (as `libgsl-dev`) on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I need to upgrade them to 2.4 at least (the last version is 2.6). How do I do this? The `apt-get upgrade` command does not give me any version more than 2.1. Version 2.4 is shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 and later versions with later Ubuntu OS versions. Any easy way, or I need to install from binaries? I have googled around and I did not find a clear solution. It seems it is not possible by `apt-get` isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a way. Not straight forward but doable.
Installing from source it did not work from me. So I thought I could download a newer `deb` package, for example the latest stable GSL 2.5 version from `Ubuntu 19.10 (eoan)` as I got this info from [here](https://reposcope.com/package/libgsl-dev). Then I implemented the first 4 steps of [this procedure](https://medium.com/@george.shuklin/how-to-install-packages-from-a-newer-distribution-without-installing-unwanted-6584fa93208f), and finally installed my `libgsl-dev` by `aptitude` as described in [this further post](https://makandracards.com/makandra/47558-how-to-install-packages-from-newer-ubuntu-releases).